# what is the difference between 'alter table rename' and 'rename table'?

Tags: mysql, alter-table, table-rename

I am using MySQL. Here's an example, I want to rename a table A to B, so what's the difference between following statement:

```
alter table A rename to B;
```

and this one:

```
rename table A to B;
```

Can anyone give a detail compare between them? Is it vary based on different engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

> For **`ALTER TABLE tbl_name RENAME TO new_tbl_name`** without any other options, MySQL simply renames any files that correspond to the table ***`tbl_name`*** without making a copy. (You can also use the [`RENAME TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rename-table.html) statement to rename tables. See [Section 13.1.32, “`RENAME TABLE` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rename-table.html).) Any privileges granted specifically for the renamed table are not migrated to the new name. They must be changed manually.

As documented under [`RENAME TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rename-table.html):

> `RENAME TABLE`, unlike [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html), can rename multiple tables within a single statement:
>
> ```
> RENAME TABLE old_table1 TO new_table1,
>              old_table2 TO new_table2,
>              old_table3 TO new_table3;
> ```
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> `RENAME TABLE` does not work for `TEMPORARY` tables. However, you can use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html) to rename temporary tables.
>
> `RENAME TABLE` works for views, except that views cannot be renamed into a different database.

There are no other differences.

Comment: so, does it mean 'alter table' is faster? and also what is a TEMPORARY table?

Comment: @Suanmeiguo: No, there should be no difference in speed. As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html): "*A `TEMPORARY` table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed.*"

Comment: Thank you eggyal. Here's more detail about temporarytable. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html